# WPF Scheduler Print or Export to PDF

Tags: wpf

I need to Print or Export to PDF, that WPF Scheduler in unbound mode...

I need to print the data, in the same way showing in the unbound mode... It means like a Screen shot...

My code :

```
DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystem ps = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystem();
PrintableComponentLink link = new PrintableComponentLink(ps);
link.Component = this.schedulerControl1;
link.ExportToPdf("123.pdf");
```

But it is showing the error as

Cannot implicitly convert type `DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduler.SchedulerControl` to `DevExpress.XtraPrinting.IPrintable`.

How to solve this???

Regards,

Kumar...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is that the PrintableComponentLink is expecting the Component property to implement a specific interface--in this case DevExpress.XtraPrinting.IPrintable.

At this point you have a couple of options. You could either create a new class that inherits SchedulerControl and implement IPrintable yourself. Or the easier approach would be to find some sort of container control that already implements IPrintable and dump your SchedulerControl in there.